# Basic operations on adjoint operators

Tags: adjoint-operators

How do you prove  :

$a^{\dagger}b^{\dagger}ba=a^{\dagger}ab^{\dagger}b$ knowing that $[b,b^{\dagger}]=[a,a^{\dagger}]=1$ and where $^{\dagger}$ denotes the adjoint.

do you need extra properties on $a$ and $b$ or is it straight forward?

Comment: You surely need something about $[a,b]$ and $[a,b^{\dagger}]$, or at least $[a,b^{\dagger}b]=0$.

Comment: The commutation properties on $a$ and $b$ are assumed to be true. The only thing to prove is is the first identity